# Disable source file path comment in esbuild output

Tags: javascript, node.js, build, esbuild

When I build my JS with `esbuild.build(options)` the original source file path is included as a comment in the output file beginning. How do i avaoid it?

```js
// C:/Users/ragha/AppData/Local/Temp/stash-creator/index.jsx
(async () => {
  await app_default();
})();
```